# React-native iOS: Could not connect to development server

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native, metro-bundler

After restarting Wi-Fi router my local ip has changed from "192.168.1.4" to "192.168.1.3" so I've changed it in AppDelegate.m to
"http://192.168.1.3:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false"

But I still get error on real device:

> Could not connect to development server ...
> URL http://192.168.1.3:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false

When I shake my phone and configure bundler to the same IP 192.168.1.3 and port 8081 app loads successfully. But Fast Refresh is not working and I need to build app and configure bundler every time I make changes in my code.

I also checked "http://192.168.1.3:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false" in my browser and on another computer in my local network and it works fine. Tried to load the same link on mobile browser with no success.
All devices are using the same network.

I have already tried:

- cleaned tmp folders and watchman
- cleaned iOS build folder
- removed and reinstalled node_modules and pods
- killed node process and restarted npm with --reset-cache
- restarted xcode, iphone and computer (many times)
- reinstalled watchman
- set "Connect via Network" in Xcode Devices window

Answer (score 1):

That was issue with expo-splash-screen package which doesn't work on new iOS version. The fact that app was not able to run after wifi restart was just a coincidence. I have seen some non-permanent warnings about splashscreen in Xcode logs but didn't take it seriously.
Removed 'expo-splash-screen' package and everything works fine.
It helped me a lot: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31369