# React Native iOS could not connect to development server

Tags: ios, react-native

I get the common `Could not connect to development server` error described in e.g. [React-native iOS: Could not connect to development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845897/react-native-ios-could-not-connect-to-development-server). Things that are working:

- My iOS device is built fine using Xcode and launching
- The URL inside the app shows correctly (`192.168.4.59:8082/index.bundle?platform=iOS&dev=true`) and opening that URL in the browser loads the bundle as it should
- The phone and laptop are on the same wifi
- Killed node process and restarted npm with --reset-cache
- Restarted xcode, iphone and computer (many times)

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It worked to use a USB cable instead of wifi and untick "Connect via Network" in `Xcode > Devices And Simulators` window.